# The right way to create a footer links area in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've created a layout with "Panels" to replace my frontpage and I have some doubts about how to populate the different panes. All my websites until now are "blog-like" websites with a typical "CMS-blog" look-like and I'm not sure what's the "Drupalish" way of solving some problems...

I'm trying to create a footer with the typical columns of links, just like the one that you can see in the bottom of "www.drupal.org". I've created 3 panes in my layout, in the footer, to "host" those links: left-link-pane, center-link-pane, right-link-pane.

My doubt is about how to populate those 3 panes with the links without creating HTML blocks...

In a youtube video I found somebody that created 3 custom full-html blocks with CSS + ul + li + a tags. That works, but It doesn't seem the right way of doing thinks in drupal.

What's the right way of doing this?

I had an idea but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, or if somebody could suggest me how to do it:

- In my panel layout, create 3 panes to host those links (links_left, links_center, links_right)
- Create a vocabulary with 3 terms (tags) named Links_left, Links_center, Links_right
- Create a new content-type named "FooterLinks" with title, body, link_text, link_url and weight.
- Create for each pane a View. Example: for the left pane, a view getting all FooterLinks tagged as "Link_left" and sorting them by their "weight", linking to "link_url".
- Use CSS Injector or a custom CSS file in the theme to give style to the results.

Maybe the above is not even possible to do with views... maybe it has to be done with "Menu entries"?

P.S. I found a module to create footers from the primary and secondary menus, but I can't control output and I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal way would be to use Menus.

Your best bet would be to use the [Footer Sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/footer_sitemap) module.

It lets you choose which menu(s) to put in the footer. And then which of the links in each to display.

So you could use a mix of your primary navigation and secondary navigation menus or create a new menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tested Footer Sitemap, but the output was not what I was expecting. Looking for similar modules, I found "menu_block", who allows "nested" menus. Now I just need to alter the style of the output (remove li bullets, style the first item or the title...)